# Function already Defined error on Discord bot

Tags: python, discord

Building from a first Discord bot by adding new commands. On creation of second command I get the error "Function already Defined" previously in the code, even though it's under a different header.

```
@client.command()
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        msg = 'Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)

My first command above, worked fine.

@client.command()
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!roll'):
        msg = 'So, {0.author.mention} you rolled for a {}'.format(random.randint(1,20))
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

Second one has an error saying async already defined previously on Line 10(In the first function)

Comment: If you want to register an event, you need to use the [`Client.event`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.event) decorator, not `Bot.command`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `def` you're defining a function. A function has to be unique, and can't be defined twice with the same name.

Solution can be

```
@client.command()
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        msg = 'Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
    elif message.content.startswith('!roll'):
        msg = 'So, {0.author.mention} you rolled for a {}'.format(random.randint(1,20))
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```